# Do veterans account for one in seven homeless US adults?

Tags: united-states, military, employment, homelessness

There seems to be a lot of attention towards unemployed/homeless military veterans in the USA. Are there any statistics or studies to show that this is some sort of pandemic, or at least unemployment/homelessness is more of a problem for ex-military than people with other careers who have lost their jobs?

According to the article [Vets Will Face Increased Challenges if Support Programs Are Cut](https://www.americanprogress.org/issues/security/news/2012/03/06/11201/veteran-poverty-by-the-numbers/):

> Nearly one in seven homeless adults are veterans, as of December 2011.

however the link to the source doesn't work for me.

Comment: It seems to me the question you are trying to ask is "Are a disproportionate number of homeless US people ex-military?" but the music video claim is about the absolute number of veteran suicides, the Quora site doesn't suggest it is disproportionate, and the reddit questyion isn't notable. Can we find a notable claim?

Comment: Here are [some potential claims](http://nchv.org/index.php/news/media/background_and_statistics/): 11% of the homeless adult population are veterans/20% of the male homeless population are veterans

Comment: Here is an article with the claim "Nearly one in seven homeless adults are veterans, as of December 2011." though the link to the citation is broken. https://www.americanprogress.org/issues/security/news/2012/03/06/11201/veteran-poverty-by-the-numbers/

Comment: The fact that the Department of Veterans Affairs is such a thing, seems to suggest people think that veterans are in need of job assistance.

Comment: Oh, there is no doubt that there is a [lot](http://www.va.gov/homeless/) of [concern](http://www.supporthomelessveterans.org/) about homeless veterans in the USA. What we are trying to establish is a claim that someone is making that you are dubious about, so we can go and find out if it is true.

Comment: OOh, [this is the closest I found](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/02/10/homeless-veterans-report-hud_n_821433.html) to what I *think* you are dubious about, but it comes with references!

Comment: 'Approx. 33% of homeless males in the U.S. are veterans'-http://www.veteransinc.org/about-us/statistics/. The sources are present here-http://nchv.org/index.php/news/media/background_and_statistics/#sources and the overrepresentation analysis of the numbers here-https://www.fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/RL34024.pdf.

Comment: Shouldn't someone ask what percentage of adults are veterans?  A quick pass through Google says anywhere from 1 in 4 to 1 in 6, so at first glance it appears veterans are less likely to be homeless than the general population.

Comment: @jamesqf I added to answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [2015 AHAR: Part 1 - PIT Estimates of Homelessness in the U.S.](https://www.hudexchange.info/resource/4832/2015-ahar-part-1-pit-estimates-of-homelessness/)

> More than one in ten homeless adults was a
>   veteran, 47,725 homeless veterans or 11 percent
>   of 436,921 homeless adults.

According to the [US census bureau](https://www.census.gov/how/pdf/census_veterans.pdf):

> There are 21.8 million veterans in the United States

And the [total number of adults](http://quickfacts.census.gov/qfd/states/00000.html) is 242 million.

So 9% of adults are veterans.

So looking at all adults, veterans are more often homeless than the general population.

However, the overrepresentation of veterans among homeless is explained by overrepresentation of males (339,075) among homeless people and veterans (over 90%).

Comment: Good answer.  It would also be interesting to look at homelessness as a function of time since separation from the military.  It could be (as it was with me) that many vets just don't want to settle in one place for a while after leaving the regimented military life.

Comment: @jamesqf I had to change the answer a lot, because I wasn't limiting to "adults" originally.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2014, the veteran homeless count stands at 11% of US Homeless Adult population. The source is mentioned [here](https://www.fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/RL34024.pdf) as U.S. Department of Housing and Urban Development, The 2014 Annual Homeless Assessment Report (AHAR) to Congress, PART 1 Point-in-Time Estimates of Homelessness, October 2014.